# Javascript double event firing unwanted

Tags: javascript, events, mootools

I want to perfom the same action for 2 different events firing. The problem I have is that one of the event fire the other. I'm using javascript and Mootools, also events are set on an 'input' element, which is inside a td cell.

I want to fire action 'save' when the element looses focus (onBlur) AND also when the user presses 'Enter' Key (onKeypressed). The problem comes from that the "save" action fire itself the 'onBlur' event. So when I press 'enter' save action is perfomed 2 times and it creates an unwanted behavior from the script.

**Here's the 'save' function** ('this' stands for the input elem)

`storeUpdt(this);
this.getParent().appendText(this.value);
this.getParent().addEvent(....);
this.destroy();`

So if you have any idea, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a mutex to block the second event handler.

```
function fireSave(event) {
  if (this._saving) {
    return;
  }
  try {
    this._saving = true;
    // do whatever stuff
  }
  finally {
    this._saving = false;
  }
}

function onKeyPressed(event) {
  // make sure the pressed key is ENTER
  fireSave();
}

var input = document.getElementById('whatever_input_id');
input.addEventHandler('blur', fireSave, false);
input.addEventHandler('keypressed', onKeyPressed, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

i know, this is obviously over-engineered but what i tend to do is have just 1 event handler and then use the other to call the first.

eg: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/VaZGC/

```
var input = document.id("myinput"), output = document.id("output"), saveValues = function(what) {
    output.set("html", what);
};

input.addEvents({
    blur: function() {
        saveValues(this.get("value"));
    },
    keyup: function(e) {
        if (e.key == "enter") {
            this.blur(); // this will be just fine.
        }
    }
});
```

you can also do `.fireEvent("blur", event)` but it's not practical here because although it will call the saveValues, it won't blur and then upon blurring it will run it again.

Comment: Don't know if I wrote it the right way, but it didn't work ?!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that keypress event firing has a lot of different behaviour depending on the browser! At the time I was working with Chrome, and the trick "enter key press fire blur event" did not work but with Opera it worked just fine.

So I finally decided to use Mootools specific keypress event manager, and it worked just fine with any browser (including the 'Tab' event!).
Hope it'll help!